# Error: Failed to create managed resources: Unable to locate credentials (sam deploy --guided)

Tags: aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

after I run `sam deploy --guided` then I got `Error: Failed to create managed resources: Unable to locate credentials`  I set `sudo aws configure` with aws access key and aws secret key already
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtucP.png)

as default user and also add another user as this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF9YT.png)
but it still can not deploy to server

here is config file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZCpF.png)

here is credential file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrNrd.png)

I wonder that why it say need credential since i add it or i need to deploy as another `--profile user2`

Comment: Take a look at the following link to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

I have a credentials file that looks like this:

```
[local-test-profile]
aws_access_key_id=xxxxx
aws_secret_access_xxxxx
aws_session_token=xxxxx
```

to get it to acknowledge this profile I did the following:

```
 sam deploy --guided --profile local-test-profile
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I had to ensure a correct aws cli.
with this version it worked for me:

aws-cli/2.2.5 Python/3.8.8 Darwin/20.3.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off

Here I had to run

> aws configure

following these steps. Even though access key id and secret access key where both set before in "~/.aws/credentials"

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-set-up-credentials.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the account user currently configured with the aws configure in your system.
Most likely that user account is not authorized to create IAM roles. You can go login as root then give the 'user' permission to create IAM role.